# Using a describe block for multiple related files in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

If I have a group of related tests that I don't want to have in one file but I still want to wrap them all in a `describe` block how can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Jasmine doesn't supply a way to do this out of the box, because you pass in a function as the second argument to `describe`, there isn't a way to combine any given functions, even if jasmine was trying to detect that some subset of your `describe`s had the same description. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by having multiple files in the same describe, but a few things I can think of are:

1. If your goal is to have the specs fall under the same filter in the html reporter, this should happen automatically if the describes are all named the same. When the html reporter checks whether a spec should be run based on the `spec=` query param, the term is checked against the beginning of full name of the spec.
2. If all of the specs need to have a shared `beforeEach` or `afterEach`, what you can do is define a method in a shared file (e.g. specHelper.js), and then call that method from a `beforeEach` or `afterEach` from within each file.

If you want both, there should be no problems with combining both approaches above.

Comment: My use case is that my integration tests are getting really long for one file. I rather split it up into `GET /`, `POST /`, etc files. However, I'd like it shown in the reporter that it still shows up in the same parent describe block (e.g. `/users`)

Answer (score 0):

You can have few `describe` with same spec suite title (first describe string parameter). Then even if specs are in separate files - they will appear in same `describe` block. It does work for me in 2.3.4.

Comment: How did you get that working? A config value or something?

Comment: For me it will just create a separate parent `describe` block of the same name.